# Remove outer brackets from my list

Tags: python

I have a loop resulting in a list consisting of lists with data(eg: `data1=[[t1],[t2],[t3]]`, however, the number of `t`'s is unknown). This list will be subjected to an ANOVA using this method:

```
from scipy import stats
f_val, p_val = stats.f_oneway(data1)
```

this function, however only accepts data in the form

```
f_val, p_val = stats.f_oneway([t1],[t2],[t3])
```

my algorithm only yields this form:

```
f_val, p_val = stats.f_oneway([[t1],[t2],[t3]])
```

My question: How do I get rid of the outer brackets?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a variable number of arguments, use the `*iterable` call notation to apply all elements in `iterable` as separate arguments:

```
f_val, p_val = stats.f_oneway(*data1)
```

Comment: wow, thank you! one single character is the solution to two hours of frustration.